# USB stopped working on the back of my tower but not the front, and then after a reboot they work again

Tags: usb, 23.04

- OS: Ubuntu 23.04
- Motherboard: ASRock X399 Taichi
- Kernel version: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic
- Processor: AMD Ryzen™ Threadripper™ 1920X × 24

Sometimes I leave my desktop Suspended overnight and sometimes the USB ports in the back stop working.  If I unplug the mouse and keyboard from the back and plug them into the front of my tower then, they work again.

If I reboot all my USB ports work again, for the mean time.

I don't want to always have to reboot my machine just to get all of my USB ports to work, I just want to restart the USB ports.

Or stop them from going wrong in the first place.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start with some diagnostics. With the ports working run `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lspci | grep -i usb` to identify the USB devices and the controllers. Then when those ports fail, run those same commands. It might also be helpful to run `sudo dmesg | grep -i usb` to look for any errors. If anything looks interesting, please edit your question directly. I'm curious to know if the hardware is still getting reported when those ports fail and/or errors are getting generated upon failure. Good luck.